# AutoCorrect Text C# Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop, spell-checking

I'm trying to use word to automatically correct some text that is not in English the problem is that when i use the SpellCheck function the "Spell and Grammar" dialog box pop-up and waits for users input and i want the text to be corrected automatically. So my question is  how do i solve this ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using TobyCL.ro.toby.StringOperations;
namespace namespace.ro.toby
{
    class WordProofing:IProof
    {
        private readonly Word.Application _wordApp;
        private readonly Word.Document _wordDoc;
        private static object _oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
        public WordProofing()
        {

            _wordApp = new Word.Application {Visible = false};
            _wordDoc = _wordApp.Documents.Add();
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            object obj = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            _wordDoc.Close(ref obj);
            _wordApp.Quit(ref obj);
        }
        #region Implementation of IProof

        public string Proof(string proofText)
        {
            Range wRng = _wordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref _oEndOfDoc).Range;
            wRng.Text = proofText;
            _wordDoc.CheckSpelling(IgnoreUppercase: true,AlwaysSuggest:false);
            string str = wRng.Text;
            wRng.Text = "";
            return str;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I wrote this code a few days ago and it worked. The problem is that i uninstall proofing tools to run some tests and now i keep getting that dialog so i'm thinking that may i have to set some Word settings or i've changed something in my code without knowing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Microsoft Office Word 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whoever might be interested this is the way i managed to solve it, but it really takes a lot of time so any improvements or new ideas are welcomed.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    class WordProofing
    {
        private Application _wordApp;
        private readonly Document _wordDoc;
        private static object _oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
        public WordProofing()
        {

            _wordApp = new Application { Visible = false };
            _wordDoc = _wordApp.Documents.Add();
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            _wordDoc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            _wordApp.Quit();
        }

        public string Proof(string proofText)
        {
            Range wRng = _wordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref _oEndOfDoc).Range;
            wRng.Text = proofText;
            ProofreadingErrors spellingErros = wRng.SpellingErrors;
            foreach (Range spellingError in spellingErros)
            {
                SpellingSuggestions spellingSuggestions =
                    _wordApp.GetSpellingSuggestions(spellingError.Text,IgnoreUppercase:true);

                foreach (SpellingSuggestion spellingSuggestion in spellingSuggestions)
                {
                    spellingError.Text = spellingSuggestion.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            string str = wRng.Text;
            wRng.Text = "";
            return str;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which MS Word version are you using?

By default the spell checker will show you the dialog box. To disable the dialog box there are two ways that I know.

1) Using Code, automatically choose the first option from Auto Correct.

It is something like this

```
AutoCorrect.Entries.Add Name:="AdSAD", Value:="Assad"
```

2) Or use the menu option. Please refer to this link.

**Topic**: **Automatically correct spelling with words from the main dictionary**

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/automatically-correct-spelling-with-words-from-the-main-dictionary-HA010174790.aspx

Do let me know if this is not what you want?

Comment: the menu option is allready set and i still keep getting the dialog, as for the first option i don't rewlly get it i'm interested in using the suggestions provided by word nit my own.